# RegEx validation for password in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to validate password entered by user.
It should be minimum 8 chars with no special char.

I have written the below code. but when i am running it, it is returning me as false.

```
$NewUserPwd = "86rqUjUJ"
$RegExForPwd = @"
(?=^.{8,12}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z]
"@

$Validate_Password = $RegExForPwd -cmatch $NewUserPwd
```

Please let me know what i am missing here.

Comment: You flipped the operands. It should be `string -cmatch pattern`, not the other way around. Also, if the only conditions are 8+ characters and no special characters the expression could be reduced to `$NewUserPwd -match '^[a-z0-9]{8,}$'`.

Comment: You mean `$NewUserName -cmatch $RegExForPwd`..???There should be 1 number and 1 upper case letters in the pwd.

Comment: Then add `-and $NewUserPwd -cmatch '[A-Z]' -and $NewUserPwd -match '\d'`. No need to cram everything into a single expression.

Comment: Still returning False `$Validate_Password = $NewUserName -cmatch '^[a-z0-9]{8,}$' -and $NewUserPwd -cmatch '[A-Z]' -and $NewUserPwd -match '\d'`

Comment: Watch the variable name. `$NewUserName`???

Comment: Please read closely. It's `$NewUserPwd`, not `$NewUserName`, and `-match`, not `-cmatch` (in the first clause). If you want to use the latter you must change that first regex to `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$`.

Comment: Sorry missed those....Done...Thanks...